How can I install pygraphviz?
I try to Install this library "pygraphviz" in python but I face this problem :
Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.12.tar.gz (104 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
  WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building pygraphviz using PEP 517
  Building wheel for pygraphviz (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pygraphviz (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [55 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\agraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_attribute_defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_clear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_close.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_drawing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_edge_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_graph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_html.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_node_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_repr_mimebundle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_string.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_subgraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      running egg_info
      writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      running build_ext
      building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\pygraphviz
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DSWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR -DGVDLL "-IC:\Users\HIGH TECH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include" "-IC:\Users\HIGH TECH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcpygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj
      graphviz_wrap.c
      pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(3020): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pygraphviz, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried many different ways but didn't works

PyGraphviz is a Python interface to the Graphviz. To compile PyGraphviz you need to have Graphviz — both the library and development files (headers). Or install precompiled with conda. See https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html

If you can use msys2, it has mingw-w64-python-graphviz package. just pacman -Sy mingw-w64-python-graphviz.
